# How do I use a different maven version for a snapcraft build?

Tags: snap, maven-3

My application https://github.com/elexis/elexis-3-core needs maven 3.0.5 to build correctly, whereas snapcraft uses the 3.3.9 as provided by Ubuntu 16.04.

Is there any way on howto require a different maven version for the build?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a patch to the relevant snapcraft plugin, adding a field to the parameters that tells the plugin to use a different version of Maven. I suspect the best way to do that will be to point to the download location of the maven you want to use (PPA etc).